Javascript not making cookie
I am working on Salesforce marketing cloud.
I have created a chrome extension using JavaScript. What it has to do is , when user enters username and hits "Next" button , it has to copy the value of Username and create a cookie
The url is https://mc.exacttarget.com/cloud . when you enter it , it navigates to "https://mc.login.exacttarget.com/hub-cas/login%5C*
I have 2 files
Manifest.json :
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "SFMC Login Tracker",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Stores the username in a cookie when a user logs into SFMC.",
    "permissions": ["cookies", "scripting", "activeTab"],
    "host_permissions": ["https://mc.login.exacttarget.com/hub-cas/login*"], 
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://mc.login.exacttarget.com/hub-cas/login*"], 
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ]
  }
  

Second is the JavaScript:
// Function to set a cookie with a specified name, value, and expiration in days
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
  const date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  const expires = "expires=" + date.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

// Function to extract the username when the form is submitted
function handleLogin() {
  // Select the username input field; adjust the selector to match the SFMC login page
  const usernameField = document.querySelector("input[name='username']");
  console.log("The username is :"+usernameField);
  if (usernameField) {
    const username = usernameField.value;

    // Set a cookie with the username, valid for 7 days
    setCookie("ActiveUser", username, 7);
    console.log(`Cookie set: ActiveUser=${username}`);
  }
}

// Attach the handler to the login form submit event
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const loginForm = document.querySelector("LoginForm"); // Adjust if needed
  if (loginForm) {
    loginForm.addEventListener("submit-btn", handleLogin);
  }
});

Somehow its not creating cookie as expected. i am not sure what i am doing wrong
When i go to inspect in chrome , i was expecting a cookie with name as ActiveUser be there

Could it be that you neglected to include the text "expires"? You add the date immediately after the cookie value, but probably should be name + "=" + value + ";expires="+expires + ";path=/". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

The issue lies in your script's event listener and the element selectors for the login form and submit action. Here's a breakdown:

Selector Issues:

Your document.querySelector("LoginForm") likely doesn't match any element. Replace it with the correct selector for the login form element.
Similarly, "submit-btn" as the event name for addEventListener is incorrect; the event name should be "submit" for forms or "click" for buttons.

Handling Delayed DOM Availability:

Ensure the DOM is fully loaded before trying to select elements. You're already using DOMContentLoaded, but verify the elements are present.
Updated content.js:
// Function to set a cookie with a specified name, value, and expiration 
in days
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
const date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
const expires = "expires=" + date.toUTCString();
document.cookie = `${name}=${value};${expires};path=/`;
}

// Function to extract the username and set a cookie
function handleLogin(event) {
event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting immediately
const usernameField = document.querySelector("input[name='username']"); // Adjust selector if needed
if (usernameField) {
const username = usernameField.value.trim();
if (username) {
  setCookie("ActiveUser", username, 7);
  console.log(`Cookie set: ActiveUser=${username}`);
} else {
  console.log("Username field is empty.");
}
} else {
console.log("Username field not found.");
}
}

// Wait for DOM content to load before attaching listeners
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
const loginButton = document.querySelector("button[type='submit']"); // Adjust if it's not a button
if (loginButton) {
 loginButton.addEventListener("click", handleLogin);
} else {
console.log("Login button not found.");
  }
});

